# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'pipeline' in Keras Python

Tags: python, keras, attributeerror, tf.keras

I’ve  made a program in Python that uses the keras module. When I ran my program, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arpit\Desktop\demo\my_approach\get_image.py", line 31, in <module>
    keras_ocr(image='sampl.png')
  File "C:\Users\arpit\Desktop\demo\my_approach\get_image.py", line 23, in keras_ocr
    pipeline = keras_ocr.pipeline.Pipeline()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'pipeline'
```

I was trying to read text from an image using keras-ocr but got the the above error.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the fact that `keras_ocr.pipeline` itself is a function and, thus, `<function>.Pipeline()` is an incorrect statement. So I believe that there is an issue with how you import the library.

Could you provide more information, or maybe a snippet of the code?

Comment: Yes, I see the problem now, thanks !!